# How can we invoke a Java UDF in XText Grammar?

Tags: java, xtext

I am working on a DSL wherein I am supposed to call Java Functions I have written. How can they be called in XText Grammar definition rules ?

Example
`Sample.xtext
Data:
    'Data'':'
        (objectRules += ObjectRule)+ //Call to Java Function here
;`

I am writng the grammar and I want to invoke Java Function to perform further processing like pasting a block of code when the Rule is encountered.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you ask questions please give as much information as possible. The more information and detail you give, the better answers you will get. If it is possible you should also add some code examples, of what you have and what you allready tryed. Thanks

Comment: Yes Springrbua. I'll try to put as much information as possible next time onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation on Xbase if you want to use Java from your Xtext languages.

The pattern would be something like this:

```
grammar org.acme.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase
generate ..
MyConcept:
  operation=ID '(' ')' body = XBlockExpression
;
```

This would allow things like

```
myOperation() {
  System.out.println("")
}
```